# Past Perfect and Stative Passive

Tags: tense

Can we use the Stative Passive  instead of the Past Perfect tense? for example:
I was driving along the road when I saw a car which ***had broken/was broken*** down. I stopped to help them.

Comment: Notice that you used a different tense there: *was broken down* ≠ *had been broken down*; *had broken down* ≠ *broke down*. Also, *the car was broken down* isn't the passive version of the active *the car broke down* (or *the car had broken down*).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["My car was breakdown" / "My car had been breakdown"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32847/my-car-was-breakdown-my-car-had-been-breakdown). Maybe this answers your question, however. (Take a look at the top voted answer.)

Comment: As a native speaker, I would naturally assume *had broken down* to be describing a verb—it "broke". On the other hand, I would assume *was broken down* to be describing an adjective—it was "dilapidated." But there is nothing wrong with either sentence. It just depends on what you're trying to communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both correct, and in your example they are synonymous, though they are not interchangeable in general.

To say that a car "had broken down" means that it had broken down *at some previous time* — but perhaps it had since been fixed (or replaced, or destroyed); so, for example, we can say:

> I finally got a new car last week; my old car had broken down one too many times.

To say that a car "was broken down" means that it was in a broken-down state *at a specific time* or *during a specific time-period*; so, for example, we can say:

> Technically I owned the car for almost a year, but it was broken down for a total of eight months of that time.

(By contrast, the converse constructions — *"my car was broken down many times" and *"my car had broken down for eight months" — are not grammatical, or at least, not with the intended meanings.)

In your example, however, both work just fine: with "had broken down" it doesn't *explicitly* say that the car was *still* broken down; and with "was broken down" it doesn't *explicitly* say that the car had entered that state *by breaking down*; but in both cases it's all completely clear from context and real-world knowledge.